React native metro loading stopped
React native metro loading stopped nothing happened ctrl + c or anything how can fix that?
Web C:\Users\pranj\OneDrive\Desktop\Mobile App\FakeStore\FakeStore\node_modules\expo/AppEntry.js ▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░ 36.1% (179/298)
I want to solve like open up project

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
